# How to create JSON file with double quotes using TextBlob

Tags: python, json

I'm using a bit of code I found online which uses TextBlob in Python to analyze sentiments of Tweets and the JSON file it generates uses single quotations whereas I need it to use double quotations. I cannot figure out how to change this in the code, so I was wondering if someone with more knowledge than me would be able to help.

I've already tried replacing single quotes in Notepad++ with double quotes, but obviously that's a bit tricky as I would want to NOT replace actual quotation marks and apostrophe's that were written in the Tweets.

```
"""
Author: Stephen W. Thomas
Perform sentiment analysis using TextBlob to do the heavy lifting.
"""
from textblob import TextBlob
import csv
import re
import operator

tweets = []

def strip_non_ascii(string):
    stripped = (c for c in string if 0 < ord(c) < 127)
    return ''.join(stripped)

#LOAD AND CLEAN DATA
with open("bachelormonday_tweets.csv", "rt") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:

        tweet= dict()
        tweet["orig"]=row[0]

        tweet["TextBlob"] = TextBlob(tweet["clean"])
        tweets.append(tweet)

# DEVELOP MODELS
for tweet in tweets:
    tweet["polarity"] = float(tweet["TextBlob"].sentiment.polarity)
    tweet["subjectivity"] = float(tweet["TextBlob"].sentiment.subjectivity)

    if tweet["polarity"] >= 0.1:
        tweet["sentiment"] = 'positive'
    elif tweet["polarity"] <= -0.1:
        tweet["sentiment"] = 'negative'
    else:
        tweet["sentiment"] = 'neutral'

tweets_sorted = sorted(tweets, key=lambda k: k["polarity"])
print(tweets)
```

What I want is a text output that has double quotations around the elements, but what I get is something like this:

```
{
    'orig': 'Who else is waiting for that fence jump from #TheBachelor?? Show us the goods already! @chrisbharrison @coltonpic.twitter.com/x2sMwgmVxg',
    'clean': 'who else is waiting for that fence jump from #thebachelor?? show us the goods already! @chrisbharrison @coltonpic.twitter.com/x2smwgmvxg',
    'TextBlob': TextBlob("who else is waiting for that fence jump from #thebachelor?? show us the goods already! @chrisbharrison @coltonpic.twitter.com/x2smwgmvxg"),
    'polarity': 0.0,
    'subjectivity': 0.0,
    'sentiment': 'neutral'
  },
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `json` module?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], with the focus on minimal. The code you present does much more than needed to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Note that `TextBlob("...")` is not valid JSON. What do you want the resulting JSON to have in place of that?

Comment: Barmar, it doesn't really matter much because all that interests me is the original tweet and the sentiment. I'm not very good at Python and definitely not good at manipulating JSON, so that's why I've come here to seek help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `json` module. You'll probably have to leave out the `TextBlob` element, since it doesn't have a JSON representation.

```
import json

...

print(json.dumps(tweets))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I got the code to work with your suggestion